# Apache Ignite - Node running on remote machine not discovered

Tags: ignite

**Apache Ignite Version is: 2.1.0**

I am using TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder to configure the nodes in an Apache Ignite cluster to setup a compute grid. Below is my configuration which is nothing but the example-default.xml, edited for the IP addresses:

```
    <property name="discoverySpi">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
            <property name="ipFinder">
                <!--
                    Ignite provides several options for automatic discovery that can be used
                    instead os static IP based discovery. For information on all options refer
                    to our documentation: http://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cluster-config
                -->
                <!-- Uncomment static IP finder to enable static-based discovery of initial nodes. -->
                <!--<bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">-->
                <!-- <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">  -->
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                    <property name="addresses">
                        <list>
                            <!-- In distributed environment, replace with actual host IP address. -->
                            <value>xxx.40.16.yyy:47500..47509</value>
                            <value>xx.40.16.zzz:47500..47509</value>
                        </list>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
```

If I start multiple nodes on individual machine, the nodes on respective machines discover each other and form a cluster. But, the nodes on the remote machines do not discover each other.

Any advise will be helpful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, make sure that you really use this config file and not a default config. With default configuration, nodes can find each other only on the same machine.

Once you've checked it, you also need to test that it's possible to connect from host 106.40.16.64 to 106.40.16.121(and vice versa) via 47500..47509 ports. It's possible that there is a firewall blocked connections or these ports is simply closed.

For example, it's possible to check it with **netcat**, run this from 106.40.16.64 host:

```
nc -z 106.40.16.121 47500
```

Comment: Hello Zhuravlev, I am trying to implement ignite on two different Ec2 instances. can 2 nodes discover each other without providing IP address?

Comment: Thank you for your response, I can't depend on s3 based discovery, sometimes I need to deploy in physical infra also so is there any other way to implement TCP discovery. without giving IP's

Comment: For example, you can use zookeper: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/zookeeper-discovery, or any other implementation, which work for you: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/tcpip-discovery. Additionally, you can implement your own IpFinder

Comment: I really appreciate your help, is there any way to implement physical ignite servers find each other and join in cluster without providing hostname or ip address. without zookeeper ,

Comment: if you will check the second link I've shared earlier, then you will find it. Why didn't you read it?

Comment: I have read it , multicast is not working in aws and staticip finder also not working

i provided logs here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50871215/apache-ignite-node-not-able-to-join-grid

Comment: But it contains much more implementations, i.e. jdbc or shared file

Comment: yup but I need to use multicast or static IP finder, I am using 2 docker container in 2 different machines(ec2) all ports are opened but not able join in the grid  below are logs, I can see in logs it's accepting connection and disconnecting