# Apache ignite node not able to join grid

Tags: ignite

I'm using static ipfinder configuration installed 2 ignite docker container in 2 different ec2 instances

but nodes not able to join each other below are logs

```
[07:40:10,696][INFO][disco-event-worker-#41][GridDiscoveryManager] Topology snapshot [ver=46, servers=2, clients=0, CPUs=6, offheap=3.8GB, heap=2.0GB]
[07:40:10,696][INFO][disco-event-worker-#41][GridDiscoveryManager] Data Regions Configured:
[07:40:10,696][INFO][disco-event-worker-#41][GridDiscoveryManager]   ^-- default [initSize=256.0 MiB, maxSize=3.1 GiB, persistenceEnabled=false]
[07:40:10,697][INFO][exchange-worker-#42][time] Started exchange init [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=46, minorTopVer=0], crd=true, evt=NODE_JOINED, evtNode=05bece82-1950-4fc0-a58e-c062ad4e9b18, customEvt=null, allowMerge=true]
[07:40:10,697][INFO][exchange-worker-#42][GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture] Finished waiting for partition release future [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=46, minorTopVer=0], waitTime=0ms, futInfo=NA]
[07:40:10,697][INFO][exchange-worker-#42][time] Finished exchange init [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=46, minorTopVer=0], crd=true]
[07:40:10,697][WARNING][disco-event-worker-#41][GridDiscoveryManager] Node FAILED: TcpDiscoveryNode [id=05bece82-1950-4fc0-a58e-c062ad4e9b18, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 127.0.0.1, 172.17.0.1, 172.19.0.1, 192.168.1.202], sockAddrs=[/172.17.0.1:47500, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500, /172.19.0.1:47500, /192.168.1.202:47500], discPort=47500, order=46, intOrder=24, lastExchangeTime=1529048390669, loc=false, ver=2.4.0#20180305-sha1:aa342270, isClient=false]
[07:40:10,698][INFO][disco-event-worker-#41][GridDiscoveryManager] Topology snapshot [ver=47, servers=1, clients=0, CPUs=4, offheap=3.1GB, heap=1.0GB]
[07:40:10,698][INFO][disco-event-worker-#41][GridDiscoveryManager] Data Regions Configured:
[07:40:10,698][INFO][disco-event-worker-#41][GridDiscoveryManager]   ^-- default [initSize=256.0 MiB, maxSize=3.1 GiB, persistenceEnabled=false]
[07:40:10,699][INFO][disco-event-worker-#41][GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture] Coordinator received all messages, try merge [ver=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=46, minorTopVer=0]]
[07:40:10,699][INFO][disco-event-worker-#41][GridCachePartitionExchangeManager] Merge exchange future [curFut=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=46, minorTopVer=0], mergedFut=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=47, minorTopVer=0], evt=NODE_FAILED, evtNode=05bece82-1950-4fc0-a58e-c062ad4e9b18, evtNodeClient=false]
[07:40:10,699][INFO][disco-event-worker-#41][GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture] finishExchangeOnCoordinator [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=46, minorTopVer=0], resVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=47, minorTopVer=0]]
[07:40:10,700][INFO][disco-event-worker-#41][GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture] Finish exchange future [startVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=46, minorTopVer=0], resVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=47, minorTopVer=0], err=null]
[07:40:10,701][INFO][tcp-disco-srvr-#3][TcpDiscoverySpi] TCP discovery accepted incoming connection [rmtAddr=/53.247.167.223, rmtPort=50787]
[07:40:10,701][INFO][tcp-disco-srvr-#3][TcpDiscoverySpi] TCP discovery spawning a new thread for connection [rmtAddr=/53.247.167.223, rmtPort=50787]
[07:40:10,701][INFO][tcp-disco-sock-reader-#133][TcpDiscoverySpi] Started serving remote node connection [rmtAddr=/53.247.167.223:50787, rmtPort=50787]
[07:40:10,702][INFO][exchange-worker-#42][GridCachePartitionExchangeManager] Skipping rebalancing (nothing scheduled) [top=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=47, minorTopVer=0], evt=NODE_JOINED, node=05bece82-1950-4fc0-a58e-c062ad4e9b18]
[07:40:10,704][INFO][tcp-disco-sock-reader-#133][TcpDiscoverySpi] Finished serving remote node connection [rmtAddr=/53.247.167.223:50787, rmtPort=50787
```

Comment: Did you export all ports in docker images: 11211 47100 47500 49112?

Comment: yup, I ran docker container with --net=host  so docker container uses all host networking and opened all ports in securitygroup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can forward 1st container's host name to the ignite node of 2nd container via a system environment variable in your ignite configuration:

```
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
    <property name="addresses">
        <list>
            <value>#{systemEnvironment['IGNITE_HOST'] ?: '127.0.0.1'}:47500..47509</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

An example of `docker-compose.yml` for 2 communicated ignite services:

```
version: "3"
services:
  ignite:
    image: image_name1
    networks:
      - net
  face:
    image: image_name2
    depends_on:
      - ignite
    networks:
      - net
    environment:
      IGNITE_HOST: 'ignite'
```

The ignite node of 'face' can connect to the another ignite node of 'ignite' using the address `ignite:47500..47509`

Answer (score 0):

Try use internal IP addresses as from this answer http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/Ignite-docker-container-not-able-to-join-in-cluster-td22080.html